# In django, is it possible to sort the admin page using a function (cannot be written with query expressions) without using raw SQL?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have this admin page class:

```py
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    levelfunc = lambda usr: dox_user(usr).rank.level

    list_display = ('name', levelfunc)
```

My ultimate goal is to be able to sort the admin page using the levelfunc column, sadly django won't allow that.

I tried googling a lot and most of the times it said to use a query expression which I cant in this situation because the dox_user function which returns data about the user cannot be simplified to an SQL expression and I can't move the dox_user function to anywhere else because I'll need to rewrite a lot of code if I do that.

Is there even a simple way to just sort it by the user's level?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use `ordering` in your meta options (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/options/#ordering), otherwise you can write a `get_queryset(..)` method on your UserAdmin (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset).